# User-defined conversion operator from base class

Tags: c#, casting

**Introduction**

I am aware that "user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed". MSDN gives, as an explanation to this rule, "You do not need this operator."

I do understand that a user-defined conversion *to* a base class is not needed, as this obviously done implicitly. However, I do need a conversion *from* a base class.

In my current design, a wrapper of unmanaged code, I use a pointer, stored in an Entity class.
All the classes using a pointer derive from that Entity class, for example, a Body class.

I therefore have:

**Method A**

```
class Entity
{
    IntPtr Pointer;

    Entity(IntPtr pointer)
    {
        this.Pointer = pointer;
    }
}

class Body : Entity
{
    Body(IntPtr pointer) : base(pointer) { }

    explicit operator Body(Entity e)
    {
        return new Body(e.Pointer);
    }
}
```

This cast is the illegal one. (Note that I didn't bother writing the accessors).
Without it, the compiler *will* allow me to do:

**Method B**

```
(Body)myEntity
...
```

However, at runtime, I will get an exception saying this cast is impossible.

**Conclusion**

Therefore here I am, needing an user-defined conversion *from* a base class, and C# refuses it to me. Using method A, the compiler will complain but the code would logically work at runtime. Using method B, the compiler will not complain but the code will obviously fail at runtime.

What I find strange in this situation is that MSDN tells me I do not need this operator, and the compiler acts *as if* it was possible implicitly (method B). What am I supposed to do?

I am aware that I can use:

**Solution A**

```
class Body : Entity
{
    Body(IntPtr pointer) : base(pointer) { }

    static Body FromEntity(Entity e)
    {
        return new Body(e.Pointer);
    }
}
```

**Solution B**

```
class Body : Entity
{
    Body(IntPtr pointer) : base(pointer) { }

    Body(Entity e) : base(e.Pointer) { }
}
```

**Solution C**

```
class Entity
{
    IntPtr Pointer;

    Entity(IntPtr pointer)
    {
        this.Pointer = pointer;
    }

    Body ToBody()
    {
        return new Body(this.Pointer);
    }
}
```

But honestly, all the syntaxes for these are horrible and should in fact be casts.
So, any way to make the casts work? Is it a C# design flaw or did I miss a possibility? It's as if C# didn't trust me enough to write my own base-to-child conversion using their cast system.

Comment: Does anyone else think the cast operator does too many things? Upcasting, downcasting, boxing/unboxing, user-defined conversions... C++ split up their cast operator years ago; maybe it's time for C# to follow suit?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's not a design flaw. Here's why:

```
Entity entity = new Body();
Body body = (Body) entity;
```

If you were allowed to write your own user-defined conversion here, there would be *two* valid conversions: an attempt to just do a normal cast (which is a reference conversion, preserving identity) and your user-defined conversion.

Which should be used? Would you *really* want is so that these would do different things?

```
// Reference conversion: preserves identity
Object entity = new Body();
Body body = (Body) entity;

// User-defined conversion: creates new instance
Entity entity = new Body();
Body body = (Body) entity;
```

Yuk! That way madness lies, IMO. Don't forget that the compiler decides this at *compile-time*, based only on the *compile-time* types of the expressions involved.

Personally I'd go with solution C - and possibly even make it a virtual method. That way `Body` *could* override it to just return `this`, if you want it to be identity preserving *where possible* but creating a new object where necessary.

Comment: You didn't understand my intention - 
I do not want to cast Body to Entity, that would be horrible.
I want to case Entity to Body. The thing is that I cannot know which class it is because I am only wrapping an unmanaged pointer.

Comment: @Lazlo: Sorry, I *did* understand your intention - I just messed up the code examples. (The variable types were right, it was just the casts that were wrong. I've fixed those now.) The reasoning behind my post remains the same, however. You want a custom conversion where there's already an explicit built-in conversion. The *clearest* way to express that desire is with a method.

Comment: (The constructor call would also be acceptable, but in some cases that can lead to less fluent code.)

Comment: @Jon: I am 200% for the existing conversion - only, it will crash at runtime. Feel free to try it yourself.

Comment: @Lazlo: You mean with an InvalidCastException? Yes, of course it will. That's the point - why disguise a new, very different conversion as if it were a completely different kind of conversion?

Comment: Extending on this good answer, I'd definetely vote for option C. It resembles discriminated unions (or composites). They are far more common and not used as much as they should be, you see them in System.Expression and F# has built-in support for them. @Jon: Maybe expand on this aspect?

Comment: @Johannes: I'm not sure I'd be able to do much more in terms of expanding... feel free to edit my post to add it in yourself though, maybe making it CW...

Answer (score 21):

Well, when you are casting `Entity` to `Body`, you are not **really** casting one to another, but rather casting the `IntPtr` to a new entity.

Why not create an explicit conversion operator from `IntPtr`?

```
public class Entity {
    public IntPtr Pointer;

    public Entity(IntPtr pointer) {
        this.Pointer = pointer;
    }
}

public class Body : Entity {
    Body(IntPtr pointer) : base(pointer) { }

    public static explicit operator Body(IntPtr ptr) {
        return new Body(ptr);
    }

    public static void Test() {
        Entity e = new Entity(new IntPtr());
        Body body = (Body)e.Pointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best alternative so far, will pick it if the bounty doesn't yield any other valuable result.

Answer (score 10):

You should use your Solution B (the constructor argument); firstly, here's why *not* to use the other proposed solutions:

- Solution A is merely a wrapper for Solution B;
- Solution C is just wrong (why should a base class know how to convert itself to any subclass?)

Also, if the `Body` class were to contain additional properties, what should these be initialized to when you perform your cast? It's far better to use the constructor and initialize the subclass's properties as is convention in OO languages.

Comment: +1 for the last argument. I'll consider it. But no way of doing it as a proper cast?

Comment: I have no problem with a base class knowing how to convert itself to a particular subclass... especially virtually. Witness Object.ToString, and the extension methods IEnumerable.ToList, IEnumerable.ToArray.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't do it is because it's not safe in the general case.  Consider the possibilities.  If you want to be able to do this because the base and derived class are interchangeable, then you really only have one class and you should merge the two.  If you want to have your cast operator for the convenience of being able to downcast base to derived, then you have to consider that not every variable typed as the base class will point to an instance of the specific derived class you are trying to cast it to.  It *might* be that way, but you would have to check first, or risk an invalid cast exception.  That's why downcasting is generally frowned upon and this is nothing more than downcasting in drag.  I suggest you rethink your design.

Comment: In my current wrapping context, the cast should be possible. I understand that in any other case, where you do not wrap an object defined as a pointer, downcasting is not recommended.

Comment: I still can't think of a reason why you wouldn't just combine the classes if they really are the same.  But if you insist, I'd say the best option is to have an explicit function GetEntityFromBody() or similar that will return an Entity object given a Body object.  That makes it clear that you are doing something out of the ordinary, while still letting you do it.  Casting should not be abused.

Comment: @siride You can't combine the classes if one of them is generic and the other is not... Such is the case with a `status` like class, where the generic version can contain a result. And the base, non-generic, class should be implicitly castable to the generic version, as it would just exist without a result. Which is a valid state.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
public class Entity {...}

public class Body : Entity
{
  public Body(Entity sourceEntity) { this.Pointer = sourceEntity.Pointer; }
}
```

so in code you don't have to write:

```
Body someBody = new Body(previouslyUnknownEntity.Pointer);
```

but you can use

```
Body someBody = new Body(previouslyUnknownEntity);
```

instead.

It's just a **cosmetic change**, I know, but it is pretty clear and you can change the internals easily. It's also used in a wrapper pattern that I can't remember a name of (for slightly diff. purposes).
It's also clear you are creating a new entity from a provided one so should not be confusing as an operator/conversion would be.

Note: haven't used a compiler so possibility of a typo is there.

Answer (score 1):

(Invoking necromancy protocols...)

Here's my use-case:

```
class ParseResult
{
    public static ParseResult Error(string message);
    public static ParseResult<T> Parsed<T>(T value);

    public bool IsError { get; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; }
    public IEnumerable<string> WarningMessages { get; }

    public void AddWarning(string message);
}

class ParseResult<T> : ParseResult
{
    public static implicit operator ParseResult<T>(ParseResult result); // Fails
    public T Value { get; }
}

...

ParseResult<SomeBigLongTypeName> ParseSomeBigLongTypeName()
{
    if (SomethingIsBad)
        return ParseResult.Error("something is bad");
    return ParseResult.Parsed(new SomeBigLongTypeName());
}
```

Here `Parsed()` can infer `T` from it's parameter, but `Error` can't, but it can return a typeless `ParseResult` that is convertible to `ParseResult<T>` - or it would be if not for this error. The fix is to return and convert from a subtype:

```
class ParseResult
{
    public static ErrorParseResult Error(string message);
    ...
}

class ErrorParseResult : ParseResult {}

class ParseResult<T>
{
    public static implicit operator ParseResult<T>(ErrorParseResult result);
    ...
}
```

And everything is happy!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the reference equality was not your concern, then you can say:

- Code

  ```
  public class Entity {
      public sealed class To<U> where U : Entity {
          public static implicit operator To<U>(Entity entity) {
              return new To<U> { m_handle=entity.Pointer };
          }

          public static implicit operator U(To<U> x) {
              return (U)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(U), x.m_handle);
          }

          To() { // not exposed
          }

          IntPtr m_handle; // not exposed
      }

      IntPtr Pointer; // not exposed

      public Entity(IntPtr pointer) {
          this.Pointer=pointer;
      }
  }
  ```

  ---

  ```
  public class Body:Entity {
      public Body(IntPtr pointer) : base(pointer) {
      }
  }

  // added for the extra demonstration
  public class Context:Body {
      public Context(IntPtr pointer) : base(pointer) {
      }
  }
  ```

and the

- Test

  ```
  public static class TestClass {
      public static void TestMethod() {
          Entity entity = new Entity((IntPtr)0x1234);
          Body body = (Entity.To<Body>)entity;
          Context context = (Body.To<Context>)body;
      }
  }
  ```

You didn't write the accessors but I took the encapsulation into account, to not expose their pointers. Under the hood of this implementation is use an *intermediate class which is not in the inheritance chain* but *chain the conversion*.

`Activator` involved here is good for not adding extra `new()` constraint as `U` are already constrained to `Entity` and have a parameterized constructor. `To<U>` though is exposed but sealed without exposing its constructor, it can only be instantiated from the conversion operator.

In the test code, the entity actually converted to a generic `To<U>` object and then the target type, so is the extra demonstration from `body` to `context`. Because `To<U>` is a nested class, it can access the private `Pointer` of the containing class, thus we can accomplish things without exposing the pointer.

Well, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use generic,
its possible like blow

```
public class a<based>
    {
        public static implicit operator b(a<based> v)
        {
            return new b();
        }
    }

    public class b
        : a<b>
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think the original request is being misunderstood.

Consider the simple situation where a base class is just serving as a grouping of related classes.

Ex:

```
class Parent ...
class Child1 : Parent ...
class Child2 : Parent ...
```

Where the programmer knows how to explicitly convert from one child class to another.

The `Parent` class can be used, for example, in:

```
Dictionary<string, Parent>
```

What I think the original request is asking for is:

How to be able to code:

```
Class1 v1 = ...
Class2 v2 = ...

v1 = v2;
```

Where inside `Parent` there is explicit code to do the conversion from `Class2` to `Class1` objects.

I have this exact situation in my code.

The best I managed to do was to add a property to `Parent` class that knows how to do the conversion and returns the proper typed object.

This forces me to write my code:

`v1 = v2.AsClass1;`

Where the property `AsClass1` in `Parent` knows how to do the actual conversion from `Class2` to `Class1`.

Honestly this is a code kludge (its ugly; detracts from from simplicity, can make expressions ridiculously long, obfuscates, and most annoyingly it lacks elegance) but its the best I could come up with.

And, yes, you guessed it, the `Parent` class also includes the `AsClass2` method :-)

All I wanted to do was:

```
v1 = v2;
```

and have the compiler silently invoke the method I specified to do the conversion.

I really don't understand why the compiler does support this :-(

In my mind this is really no different then:

```
int v1;
decimal v2;
. . .
v1 = (int)v2;
```

The compiler knows to silently invoke some built-in conversion method.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old discussion, though, but I just wanted to add some experiences of my own.

In a class library, we had once mathematical objects like 2D points AND 2D vectors. Because the features of the objects of both classes are mostly the same (although not quite the same, wherefore both classes were needed), the idea was to define a `Vector2D` and to derive `Point2D` from it. It would spare a lot of repeating definitions, but a custom conversion operator from vector to point would not be possible.

So since we strongly wanted to deliberately exchange the types in the code, we just decided to give up the idea of derivation, declared both classes independently and introduced implicit conversion operators. Then we could freely exchange both types in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ugg, I ended up just doing a simple Cast() method inside my modified entity. Maybe I am just missing the point, but I need to modify my base type so I can keep my code inside the new object to do x. I would have used public static explicit operator if the compiler would let me. The inheritance messes it up explicit cast operator.

Usage:

```
var newItem = UpgradedEnity(dbItem);
var stuff = newItem.Get();
```

Sample:

```
public class UpgradedEnity : OriginalEnity_Type
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            foreach (var item in this.RecArray)
            {
                //do something
            }
            return "return something";
        }

        public static UpgradedEnity Cast(OriginalEnity_Type v)
        {
            var rv = new UpgradedEnity();
            PropertyCopier<OriginalEnity_Type, UpgradedEnity>.Copy(v, rv);
            return rv;
        }

        public class PropertyCopier<TParent, TChild> where TParent : class
                                            where TChild : class
        {
            public static void Copy(TParent from, TChild to)
            {
                var parentProperties = from.GetType().GetProperties();
                var childProperties = to.GetType().GetProperties();

                foreach (var parentProperty in parentProperties)
                {
                    foreach (var childProperty in childProperties)
                    {
                        if (parentProperty.Name == childProperty.Name && parentProperty.PropertyType == childProperty.PropertyType)
                        {
                            childProperty.SetValue(to, parentProperty.GetValue(from));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```