# c# implicit conversion from base class

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, implicit-conversion

I have a collection class like this:

```
public class SomeDataCollection : List<ISomeData>
{
    // some method ...
}
```

but I can't do this:

```
SomeDataCollection someDatas = new List<ISomeData>();
```

> Cannot **implicitly** convert type `List<ISomeData>` to `SomeDataCollection`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

so I try to create an implicit coverter inside `SomeDataCollection` collection class:

```
public static implicit operator SomeDataCollection(List<ISomeData> l)
{
    var someDatas = new SomeDataCollection();
    someDatas.AddRange(l);
    return someDatas;
}
```

but it said that I can't create such converter:

> `SomeDataCollection.implicit operator SomeDataCollection(List<ISomeData>)`: **user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed**

And when I cast it like this:

```
SomeDataCollection someDatas = (SomeDataCollection)new List<ISomeData>();
```

it throws an error that said:

> **System.InvalidCastException:** Unable to cast object of type `List<ISomeData>` to type `SomeDataCollection`.

How can I do this:

```
SomeDataCollection someDatas = new List<ISomeData>();
```

without getting an error? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible dupplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401084/user-defined-conversion-operator-from-base-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `new List<ISomeData>();` is still just a `List<ISomeData>`. It isn't a `SomeDataCollection`. The point of subclassing is that the subclass could have extra state etc, but an object (once created) **never** changes type.

You are not allowed to create operators between types in the same hierarchy, as that would subvert the usual and expected casting behaviour.

You could use simply:

```
var data = new SomeDataCollection();
```

However I should add that frankly it is rarely useful to subclass `List<T>`. Not least, it doesn't expose any useful `virtual` methods, so you can't tweak the behaviour. I would honestly just use a `List<ISomeData>` (and remove `SomeDataCollection` completely) unless I have a clear and demonstrable purpose for it. And then: I might either *encapsulate* the list, or inherit from `Collection<T>`.

You could always just add the method as an extension method?

```
public static class Utils {
    public static void SomeMethod(this IList<ISomeData> list) {
      ...
    }
}
```

then:

```
var list = new List<ISomeData>();
...
list.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: I do not actually just put a freshly instantiated `List<ISomeData>` in `SomeDataCollection`, that was just a sample :P. I use`List<T>` because it already has some function for adding, removing, etc objects, and I have some additional methods and properties in my `SomeDataCollection` class whcih is specific only to type `List<ISomeData>`.

Comment: @John IMO having something both be a list *and* have its own state is a mistake; many frameworks/libraries *hate* that - binding, serialization, materialization, etc. IMO you should have an object which *has* those properties, and which also *has* an `IList<Foo> Items {get;}`

Comment: It is often useful to subclass List<T>. A good example might be a list that can adapt to different conditions and has properties and methods added for that purpose. However, even in those cases, T usually remains T.

Comment: @ThomasPhaneuf since `List<T>` doesn't expose any polymorphic APIs, it is unclear what it could usefully do to "adapt" to anything

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why do you want to write `new List<ISomeData>` into a variable defined as `SomeDataCollection`?
It is possible that you actually wanted to `SomeDataCollection someDatas = new SomeDataCollection();`

As for error messages, the first error message tells you that `List<ISomeData>` is not derived from `SomeDataCollection`, therefore you can't do with it something you would do with `SomeDataCollection`, therefore you can't write it to the variable which is defined as `SomeDataCollection` (imagine e.g. if `SomeDataCollection` had `public void someMethod()` in it, and later in the code you'd call `someDatas.someMethod()`).

The second error message tells you that converters are intended for converting between completely different types, not between the based and derived type. Otherwise, what would you expect to get e.g. in the following example:

```
SomeDataCollection a = new SomeDataCollection();
List<ISomeData> b = (List<ISomeData>)a;
SomeDataCollection c = (SomeDataCollection)b;
```

Should it call your converter or not?

Basically code you're trying to write is very wrong to begin for, so we need to know what're you trying to do, and then maybe well'be able to tell you the solution of your root problem (and not of the problem "how to make this code compile").

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it better to implement a constructor in `SomeDataCollection`?

```
public SomeDataCollection() : base() { }
```

This could of course be complemented with

```
public SomeDataCollection(IEnumerable<ISomeData> collection) 
    : base(collection) { }
```

Then you should be able to initialize your `SomeDataCollection` like this instead:

```
SomeDataCollection someData = new SomeDataCollection();
SomeDataCollection someOtherData = 
    new SomeDataCollection(collectionOfSomeData);
```

and still have access to all the public methods and properties in `List<ISomeData>`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not problem with generics. In C# you are not allowed to explicitely convert a base class into a derived class.