# Explicit and implicit cast with generic type

Tags: c#

I have those classes:

```
public class FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType
{
    public FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType();
    public FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType(string filterValue = null, string filterType = null);

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "filterType")]
    public string FilterType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "filterValue")]
    public string FilterValue { get; set; }
}
```

And my:

```
 public abstract class Filter<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public T Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
 public class DiscountFilter : Filter<DiscountFilterType>
{


}
```

I want to cast `DiscountFilter` to `FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType` in explicit or implicit way.

So I add operator method:

```
 public class DiscountFilter : Filter<DiscountFilterType>
{
    public static implicit operator FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType(DiscountFilter filter)
        => new FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType(filterType: filter.Type.ToString(), filterValue: filter.Value);
}
```

But it do not compile because:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Filter<DiscountFilterType>' to 'FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType'
```

How I can do it?

`DiscountFilterType` is a enum.

And FilterCreator.Create is:

```
public class DiscountFilterCreator : FilterCreator<DiscountFilterType>
{
    public override Filter<DiscountFilterType> Create(DiscountFilterType type, string value)
        => new DiscountFilter {Type = type, Value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? null : value};
}
```

It derives from:

```
public abstract class FilterCreator<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public abstract Filter<T> Create(T type, string value);
}
```

And last `Filter` is:

```
public abstract class Filter<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public T Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**
to reproduce the issue  you have to do this

```
DiscountFilter filter = new DiscountFilterCreator().Create(DiscountFilterType.normal, "wow");
```

**EDIT**

```
DiscountFilter x = this.FilterCreator.Create(DiscountFilterType.BrandId, brandId);
        FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType y = x;
```

**Edit** 
It works:

```
    DiscountFilter x = (DiscountFilter)this.FilterCreator.Create(DiscountFilterType.BrandId, brandId);
        FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType y = x;
```

but I want to do it this way:

```
    FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType  x = this.FilterCreator.Create(DiscountFilterType.BrandId, brandId);
```

So I need this implicit conversion too:

```
   public class DiscountFilter : Filter<DiscountFilterType>
{
    public static implicit operator DiscountFilter(Filter<DiscountFilterType> filter)
        => new DiscountFilter {Value = filter.Value};
    public static implicit operator FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType(DiscountFilter filter)
        => new FilterBackOfficeDiscountFilterType(filterType: filter.Type.ToString(), filterValue: filter.Value);
}
```

But the implicit casting from derivered class to base is not allowed!

```
DiscountFilter.implicit operator DiscountFilter(Filter<DiscountFilterType>): user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed
```

Comment: All code compiles here (given a few typos and duplicate type definitions, but okay).

Comment: Have you tried moving this operator to the generic class?

Comment: It's not clear what you asking because your code indeed compiles just fine.

Comment: @Evk yes the issue you can reproduce the issue  DiscountFilter filter = new DiscountFilterCreator().Create(DiscountFilterType.normal, "wow")

Comment: @PatrickHofman is not a matter of compilation of code  Nerf does not provide how to reproduce the issue

Comment: Then why did you answer? @BRAHIMKamel

Comment: @PatrickHofman Ok I know by  rules I should vote to close the question but it's easy to  reproduce the issue I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Implicit) user-defined conversions from base class to derived class are a bad idea and as such not supported by the language as already explained here: [User-defined conversion operator from base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401084/user-defined-conversion-operator-from-base-class)

As a solution to your problem, I'd propose to adjust your base types as follows:

```
public abstract class FilterCreator<TFilter, TFilterType>
    where TFilter : Filter<TFilterType>
    where TFilterType : struct
{
    public abstract TFilter Create(TFilterType type, string value);
}

public abstract class Filter<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public T Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can just implement the DiscountFilterCreator as

```
public class DiscountFilterCreator : FilterCreator<DiscountFilter, DiscountFilterType>
{
    public override DiscountFilter Create(DiscountFilterType type, string value)
        => new DiscountFilter { Type = type, Value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? null : value };
}
```

Using this, you will no longer need casts since the returned type is the expected type.

Not sure this is exactly what you want. The code seems very abstract by C#'s standards, it's probable that there is a better design for your needs.

EDIT: Just as a side note, this implementation renders the `FilterCreator` very close to useless. The usefulness of `Filter<T>` seems rather questionable as well - do you ever declare a variable or generic contraint of type `Filter<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce your issue you are trying to cast a base generic class to  a derived class.

something like this

```
DiscountFilter filter = new DiscountFilterCreator().Create(DiscountFilterType.normal, "wow");
```

to resolve your issue you have to  cast to the derived class

```
 DiscountFilter filter =(DiscountFilter) new DiscountFilterCreator().Create(DiscountFilterType.normal, "wow");
```